# Bootstrap - How to fit 7 columns in a div row with equal width and no wastage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a MEAN stack application where in html I have a `div class="row"` which has 7 columns, I have 7 columns each of which i want to give equal space and not waste space in spacing between them. When it was 6 cols, I was easily using `col-md-2`, but if I do the same for 7 columns, as expected the last column shifts to the next line. How can I fit the 7 cols in the width of the main div?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row" ng-show="show_results"  style="height:100px" >
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid #d1cfcf; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y:auto ;">
            Translation 1 <br/> <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoadingNMTLess"></md-progress-circular>
            {{data.nmt_less}}
            <br/>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid #d1cfcf; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y:auto ;">
            Translation 2 <br/> <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoadingNMTMore"></md-progress-circular>
            {{data.nmt_more}}
            <br/>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid #d1cfcf; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y:auto; " >
            Translation 3 <br/> <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoadingGoogle"></md-progress-circular>
            {{data.google}}

            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid #d1cfcf; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y:auto; ">
            Translation 4 <br> <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoadingMosesSmall"></md-progress-circular>
            {{data.moses_less}}

            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid #d1cfcf; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y:auto; ">
            Translation 5 <br> <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoadingMosesBig"></md-progress-circular>
            {{data.moses_more}}
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border:1px solid #d1cfcf; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-y:auto; ">
            Translation 6 <br> <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ng-show="isLoadingWatson"></md-progress-circular>
            {{data.watson}}
            <br/>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" >
            <label> Translation 1
                <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="checkboxModel.nmt_less"   ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
            </label>
            <label> Translation 2
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.nmt_more"   ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
            </label>
            <label> Translation 3
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.google"   ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
            </label>
            <label> Translation 4
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.moses_less"   ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
            </label>
            <label> Translation 5
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.moses_more"   ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
            </label>
            <label> Translation 6
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.watson"   ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
            </label>

         <br/>Suggest Translation</br>
         <textarea ng-model="suggestedTranslation" placeholder="Optional - your suggestion for translation" style="height: 140px;"></textarea>
         <button ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary active">  </i> Submit the best translation</button>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Can I do it using `twitter-bootstrap`? My bootstrap version is `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",`

Comment: you could create a new class which is based on the `-2` classes and change the width

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - could you elaborate? Couldn't follow you! sorry.

Comment: @Tarun create a jsfiddle

Comment: create a class something like ```.col-7-12 {
-ms-flex: 0 0 14.285714%;
    flex: 0 0 14.285714%;
max-width: 14.285714%;
}```

Comment: @yaylitzis - sorry couldn't do it because i couldn't share the javascript code.

Comment: my answer was basically the same answer

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - ya, understood it now. Thanks :)